# Application Data bundles in Xcode 6. Always crashes or shows error

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8, xcode6

How do you correctly use **Application Data** bundles in Xcode 6? I exported a `.xcappdata` file from a device, added it to my workspace, and selected it in the Run Options of a scheme.

Whenever I try to run the simulator with iOS 8.0, I get the following error, even on repeated launches, manual launches, etc:

> **Application data package not copied to the Simulator**
>   It appears you are running 'REDACTED.app' on the iPad Air Simulator for
>   the first time, and therefore do not yet have a data folder created. 
>   The application data package will be installed the next time you run
>   your app in the Simulator.

Trying to use the simulator with iOS 7.1 crashes Xcode.

Does this feature just not work anymore with the changes made to the filesystem?

---

Tried again on Xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a) and it (sometimes) crashes Xcode now, hopefully that means it will be get fixed soon...

Comment: I'm getting the same error with 6.0.1 (haven't tried 6.1 betas) in the simulator. Application Data bundles DO work correctly on the physical devices though...

Comment: I'm getting the same problem with XCode 6.1. I've filed a bug with Apple #19083330.

Comment: I got the same error so i just copied the files manually to the filesystem. you can right click on the xcappdata and show contents, and in the terminal cd to `~/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` open .default_created.plist and look through to find which UUID belongs to your device, then cd to that folder and run `open .` then use finder to copy the files into the proper folder for your app

Comment: Still have it with XCode 6.2 (6C131e)

Comment: Filed a radar (duplicating #19083330) rdar://20481684. XCode 6.2 (6C131e)

Comment: Xcode Version 6.3 (6D570) fails silently now.

Comment: I've created a git repo with a project to test if this bug is fixed or not https://github.com/Ashton-W/rdar_ApplicationDataPackage

Comment: Submitted another radar against Xcode 7.0 Beta

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Xcode 8.1 and when I tried to add the .xcappdata file Xcode crashed.

I solved it by cleaning the app and then I tried to add it in another target and it worked. Afterwards I tried to put it again in the target I wanted it in and it worked as well.

Unfortunately I'm not sure about which of these steps fixed it but I hope it to be useful to someone!

Comment: on device or simulator?

Comment: I was using a real device

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean the **Derived Data** which contains all the intermediate build information like debug- and release-built targets. And you probably can select the **Simulator**, choose the **iOS Simulator** from the menu. Then, choose **Reset Content and Setting**.

Sometimes, it's just some bugs in the XCode. And I think Apple is handling that when your issue is marked by duplicate by them.